# Preventing MITM Attack with Squid

Tags: tls, certificates, proxy, tls-intercept, squid

There are two options, what is the best approach?

I want to either

1. Create a squid proxy server that detects MITM attacks

or

2. Create a python UI application to detect differences between local certificate store and certificate sent from server. If there is a difference, show error on the client side that a possible MITM attack was prevented and then redirect user to real site. Is this possible? What programming langauge can I use for this?

Comment: `Create a squid proxy server that detects MITM attacks` --> Squid IS a proxy. 

`If there is a difference, show error on the client side that a possible MITM attack was prevented and then redirect user to real site.` --> already implemented in web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> ... and then redirect user to real site.

The characteristics of an MITM attack is that the **attacker is in the path** (in the "middle") of the traffic between client and **intended** server and modifies the traffic there.

Since the client is already trying to access the intended server a redirect will not be possible: one cannot issue a redirect to the same server but with a different network path not controlled by the attacker. One could at most try to avoid the compromised path completely, for example by cutting the DSL line and creating a connection via a mobile network or similar. How successful something like this would even be depends on the location of the attacker: if they are at the DSL ISP provider it might help to switch to mobile network instead. If the attacker is near to the server this will not help though.